# XQuery grouping in SoapUI without group by

Tags: xml, group-by, xquery, soapui, assertion

i have an xml as a response in Soap UI test step:

```
<body>
    <car>
        <color>green</color>
        <nr>88</nr>
    </car>
    <car>
        <color>yellow</color>
        <nr>54</nr>
    </car>
    <car>
        <color>red</color>
        <nr>17</nr>
    </car>
    <car>
        <color>green</color>
        <nr>18</nr>
    </car>
    <car>
        <color>yellow</color>
        <nr>56</nr>
    </car>
    <car>
        <color>red</color>
        <nr>12</nr>
    </car>
</body>
```

And i want to create an assertion that the response has colors: green, yellow, red (no matter how many).

I wrote XQuery assertion:

```
<Result>
{
for $z in //car
order by $z/color
return 
<color>{data($z/color)}</color>
}
</Result>
```

and i get the result:

```
<Result>
  <color>green</color>
  <color>green</color>
  <color>red</color>
  <color>red</color>
  <color>yellow</color>
  <color>yellow</color>
</Result>
```

but i can't group it, because it doesn't matter for me how many matches of each color in response.
I tried

```
<Result>
{
for $z in //car
group by $z/color
order by $z/color
return 
<color>{data($z/color)}</color>
}
</Result>
```

but i get an error "Invalid XQuery expression" in SoapUI 5.7.0.

Is there any way to assert the existing of certain colors with XQuery in SoapUI 5.7.0 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to fix sample XML. It is not *well-formed*.

Please try the following.

**XQuery**

```
<Result>
{
  for $z in distinct-values(/body/car/color)
  order by $z
  return <color>{$z}</color>
}
</Result>
```

**Output**

```
<Result>
  <color>green</color>
  <color>red</color>
  <color>yellow</color>
</Result>
```

Comment: Thank you!
The function distinct-values works well in SoapUI 5.7.0 XQuery assertion!

Comment: fixed not well-formed xml in my condition.